# Check if character is valid Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm converting SQL server code to Postgres and trying to check if a character in any position of a string is valid.

Code so far is (there are parts around this)

```
SELECT
string_agg(txml.substr_text,'') as stringagg
FROM (
SELECT
CASE
WHEN (substring('ÄZYasdXA', n, 1) similar to ('"[^a-zA-Z0-9_{}""""() *&%$#@!?/\;:,.—<>–+ =`|~]-"')) 
AND (substring('ÄZYasdXA', n, 1) <> '[') AND (substring('ÄZYasdXA', n, 1) <> ']')
AND (substring('ÄZYasdXA', n, 1) <> '^') 
THEN substring('ÄZYasdXA', n, 1)
ELSE '|'
END as substr_text
FROM (SELECT
* from generate_series(1,1000)) AS nums (n)
WHERE n <= LENGTH('ÄZYasdXA')) AS txml
```

I've entered an Ä in to check against that as doing the same in SQL Server is bringing that back as invalid but not doing so here. Is there something I'm  missing here, or do I need to try to change the "[^a-zA-Z0-9_'{}""""() *&%$#@!?/;:,.—<>–+ =`|~]-" part?

Comment: What do you mean if a character is valid?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?  Currently you have: `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ri"`

Comment: This is not valid code anyway, you can't put content between double quotes. What ever check you do, you should get an error message. This one works fine: SELECT  c, c similar to '[A-Z]'
FROM (VALUES('Ä'),('A')) v(c);

Comment: @FrankHeikens: When you **need** to post code in a comment please use a single back quote around that code....

Comment: I've changed code there so that the example works (my actual code runs just doesn't give me right results. I want that case statement to be outputting Ä in that example. I'm only getting the | back in the else statement there whereas I think I should be getting back Ä|||||||

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please debug your work and examine the result of this:

```sql
select 
   substring('ÄZYasdXA', 1, 1), 
   substring('ÄZYasdXA', 1, 1) similar to ('"[^a-zA-Z0-9_{}""""() *&%$#@!?/\;:,.—<>–+ =`|~]-"') test1,
   (substring('ÄZYasdXA', 1, 1) <> '[') AND (substring('ÄZYasdXA', 1, 1) <> ']') as test2,
   (substring('ÄZYasdXA', 1, 1) <> '^') as test3,
   substring('ÄZYasdXA', 1, 1) as substring2;
```

results:

| substring | test1 | test2 | test3 | substring2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ä | false | true | true | Ä |

`test` fails, so result will be equal to `|`.

You might need to change your first test to:

```
select substring('ÄZYasdXA',1,1) similar to ('[^a-zA-Z0-9_{}""""() *&%$#@!?/\;:,.—<>–+ =`|~]');
```

(which returns `true`)

Comment: Perfect, switching to that string has made it work. Thanks for that